# Seeking OSS charting library for 2-D grids, like the old Windows defrag

Tags: charts, graphing

I'd like to chart some future chunks of work on my systems.  Hours on one axis, hardware on the other, so I'd get various rectangles representing future activites, not necessarily rooted on either axis.  I'm imagining something like the old Windows defrag, with different colored blocks for each pending block.

I've looked at [flotr](http://code.google.com/p/flotr/), [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/), and some others.  They're really slick, but none of them seem to have this particular device.  Any suggestions?  ( I've also thought about just toughing it out w/ Perl and GD and rolling my own. )

Answer (score 0):

May be one of this [plots](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/en/1d_plots.html) will be OK for you? It was produced by [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) -- GPL plotting library. It is possible to set hours on axis as manual ticks (for v.1.* and v.2.0) or as time ticks (like strftime() format, only for v.2.0). Manual ticks can be used for hardware icon/text too (as Unicode symbols, for example). Also position of bars is defined by current axis origin and can be different for different series.